# What is the "Loop" partition in ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, fdisk

I'm a new user to Ubuntu, to just installed and used the command `sudo fdisk -l`.

I found out that my Windows partition is SDA and my ubuntu is `loop`.

What is this `loop` thing?

Comment: The loop device usually shows when you run Ubuntu from a Live CD/USB. It's also worth noting that Windows partitions are usually sda1 and sda2, not just sda.

Comment: @mikewhatever can you write that as answer?

Comment: @user68186 can you write that as answer?

Comment: loop means there's no partition table, just a single filesystem on the entire disk

Answer (score 7):

Also worth noting (adding **"Reason Three"** to [@user68186's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/394210)) is that `parted` shows `loop` as the "partition table" for **disks that actually do *not* have a partition table** (whole disk filesystem).

I ran into this accidentally when I wanted to get an ext4 filesystem on a brand new external NVMe M.2 SSD. Plugged it in to an USB port and used Ubuntu Desktop's *Disks* tool without getting into the details. Then I was surprised that I had no `/dev/sda1` but only `/dev/sda` to mount. Hope this is not related to the occasional I/O errors I get (probably rather a power issue, using it on a Raspberry Pi 4).

Comment: A loop partition table will also show up if you have, say, a disk retired from a zfs array, and you use dd to wipe the first two blocks  dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd bs=512 count=2 This can be fixed by running gdisk, running rescue (r), then load backup partition table from disk (c), then write the recovered partition table.  This will turn the drive into one with a gpt partition table having no defined partitions.

Answer (score 6):

## A loop device is a file containing a virtual file system inside another file system.

There are two common reasons you may be seeing `loop`

**Reason One**

You may see `loop` if you used WUBI.EXE to install Ubuntu within Windows. This creates virtual partitions in a large file within the Windows file system.

Note that WUBI does not work with computers that came pre-installed with Windows 8 or later.

**Reason Two**

(Thanks to @mikewhatever for pointing is out in the comments above)

The loop device also shows up when you run Ubuntu from a Live CD/USB. A virtual file system stored in the CD/USB/DVD is mounted as loop.

Reference: [Wiki on Loop Device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

...and an important **"Reason Four"**: confusingly, `parted` also will say `Partition Table: loop`  if you `select` a partition within a partition table rather than the root block device, eg. mistakenly calling it with `parted /dev/sdX1`.

Comment: How is this unclear?

Comment: I'd agree with ghostly_s; his answer is not unclear. It is only unclear if you never run in this error; that's what I accidentally did, and after see his answer, it became crystal clear my obvious error: call with `parted /dev/sdX` not with the partition itself like `parted /dev/sdX1`